# Finding the cutoff value using confusion matrix?

Tags: r, variable-assignment, r-caret, confusion-matrix

```
n<-1 
a<-as.vector(length(s))
for (i in s ) {

  print(i)
  test$result<-ifelse(test$pred>i,1,0)
  a[n]<-confusionMatrix(test$result,test$churn,positive = "1")$overall[2]

  print(n)
  n=n+1
}
max(a)
```

How do iget the threshold value between the above range if i run the code, I get this error

> Error in:`$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "result", value = logical(0)) : 
>     replacement has 0 rows, data has 3892

Answer (score 0):

Try `test$result[[i]]<-ifelse(test$pred[[i]]>i,1,0)`. I think that is why you're getting that error, but I am not able to reproduce the error